# don't add token to balancesOf[msg.sender]

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

This is my first smart contract and it has some errors. But I don't know where the error can you help me?

`    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

```
 contract ERC20{
 uint256 public totalSupply;
 string public name;
 string public symbol;
 mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
 mapping (address => mapping(address => uint256)) allowance;

 constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_){
    name = name_;
    symbol = symbol_;
    _mint(msg.sender, 100);
    }
 function _mint(address to , uint256 amount) internal  {
    require(to != address(0),"ERC20: mint to the zero address");
    totalSupply += amount;
    balanceOf[to] = balanceOf[to] + amount;
}
 function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns(bool){
    return _transfer(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
}
 function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external      returns(bool){
    uint256 currentAllowance = allowance[sender][msg.sender];
    require(
        currentAllowance >= amount,
        "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"
    );
    allowance[sender][msg.sender] -= currentAllowance;

    return _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
}
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns(bool){
    require( spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

    allowance[msg.sender][spender] = amount;
    return true;
}
function _transfer(address sender,address recipient, uint256 amount) private returns(bool){
    require(recipient != address(0),"ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
    uint256 senderBalances = balanceOf[sender];
    require(senderBalances >= amount,"You don't have enough token");
    balanceOf[sender] = senderBalances - amount;
    balanceOf[recipient] += amount;

    return true;

}
}`
A test file: 
import { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers"
 import { expect } from "chai";
 import { ethers } from "hardhat";
 import { ERC20 } from "../typechain-types";
 describe("ERC20",function(){
 let ERC20: ERC20;
 let someaddress: SignerWithAddress;
 let someOtheraddress: SignerWithAddress;
 beforeEach(async function () {
 const ERC20ContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("ERC20");
 ERC20 = await ERC20ContractFactory.deploy("Hello","SYM");
 await ERC20.deployed(); 
 someaddress = (await ethers.getSigners())[1];
 someOtheraddress = (await ethers.getSigners())[2];

  ;});
  describe('when i have 10 token', function() { 
  beforeEach(async function () {
    //mint 10 token
    await ERC20.transfer(someaddress.address, 10);
   });  
  });
  describe("When i transfer 10 token", function(){
   it("should transfer tokens correctly", async function(){
    await ERC20.connect(someaddress).transfer(someOtheraddress.address,10)
    expect (
      await (await ERC20.balanceOf(someOtheraddress.address))).to.equal(10);
  });
})
}); `
```

when i run and test it on remix.org it true. But when i run a test file with this code on visual studio code it return:
`Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'You don't have enough token'          at ERC20._transfer (contracts/ERC20_Contract.sol:44)     at ERC20.transfer (contracts/ERC20_Contract.sol:23)     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)     at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:533:9)     at processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)     at async HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:1819:23)     at async HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:508:16)            at async EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:1522:18)`

How i can fix this code on visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

your error points to this function

```
function _transfer(address sender,address recipient, uint256 amount) private returns(bool){
    require(recipient != address(0),"ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
    uint256 senderBalances = balanceOf[sender];
    // ------------ this is where testing is reverting
    require(senderBalances >= amount,"You don't have enough token");
    balanceOf[sender] = senderBalances - amount;
    balanceOf[recipient] += amount;

    return true;
}
```

the account that you are connected does not have enough tokens. you can chekc the balance

```
someaddress = (await ethers.getSigners())[1]
// this address does not have enough eth
console.log("Balance:", (await someAddress.getBalance()).toString());
```

the reason you are getting error, your hardhat.config.js is not configured properly. for testing

```
// make sure you import necessary packages on top 
networks: {
        // this is default
        hardhat: {
            chainId: 31337,
        },
      ...
  }
```

then run

```
  npx hardhat test
```

> When Hardhat executes your tests, scripts or tasks, an in-process
> Hardhat Network node is started automatically, and all of Hardhat's
> plugins (ethers.js, web3.js, Waffle, Truffle, etc) will connect
> directly to this node's provider.

to see the accounts you can run the node manually

```
npx hardhat node
```